# WebRTC over the internet and on LAN

Tags: webrtc, p2p, lan

While building a webrtc enabled application, do we just assume that ice candidates behind the same NAT or in the same W(LAN) transfer data to each other over the local network or will transfer data online? Or do we have to configure our code to enable local network connections and transfers specifically? If yes, then how? What needs to be changed at the client and/or server end?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

By default WebRTC will gather host (LAN) candidates.

If you want to disable LAN connectivity you can set the [iceTransportPolicy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCConfiguration#RTCIceTransportPolicy_enum) to `"relay"`

You don't need to change anything on your client/server by default. I would make sure that server you are using supports mDNS candidates if you want LAN connectivity. This is a recent change in WebRTC, but it will break some software. You can read more about it [here](https://bloggeek.me/psa-mdns-and-local-ice-candidates-are-coming/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So will I be able to achieve a local webrtc connection between say, an ios and android device if the server supported mDNS candidates?